# HERE Matrix Routing - Mapping results to original objects, C#

Tags: c#, .net, matrix, routes

I am using the HERE Matrix Routing API to get distance and duration between locations by supplying desired transport mode.

The API takes an array of origins and an array of destinations, perfect for when wanting to calculate many routes at the same. I just don't know how to map the response in a good manner.

I have 4 routes:

- Point 1 to Point 2
- Point 3 to Point 4
- Point 5 to Point 6
- Point 7 to Point 8

And so I provide the API with the latitude and longtiude for 4 origins (1,3,5,7) and 4 destinations (2,4,6,8).
I get an array with distances in the response, 12 of them.

Now how do I in a good manner write logic that can pull out the distance for my 4 routes?

HERE have documentation saying:

*Each array represents a 2D matrix where rows correspond to origins  and columns to destinations. The k-th position in the array corresponds to the (i, j) position in the matrix defined by the following
relationship: k =  num_destinations  * i + j*

https://developer.here.com/documentation/matrix-routing-api/8.3.0/api-reference-swagger.html

Sample request:

```
{
  "origins": [
    {
      "lat": 52.5309,
      "lng": 13.3849
    },
    {
      "lat": 52.5202,
      "lng": 13.373
    }
  ],
  "destinations": [
    {
      "lat": 52.522,
      "lng": 13.4133
    },
    {
      "lat": 52.5163,
      "lng": 13.3777
    }
  ],
  "regionDefinition": {
    "type": "world"
  }
}
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "matrixId": "bc79a808-dbac-4e49-88f2-27ec66a473ef",
  "matrix": {
    "numOrigins": 1,
    "numDestinations": 2,
    "travelTimes": [
      1231,
      983
    ],
    "distances": [
      109,
      10
    ]
  },
  "regionDefinition": {
    "type": "circle",
    "center": {
      "lat": 52.53787,
      "lng": 13.40896
    },
    "radius": 10000
  }
}
```

I'd very much appreciate some help to pull out the distance. I'll be requesting many different routes and I don't always know the amount so I need a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself.

My matrix is as of right now always a square and since I know that my origins and my destinations have the same index in the request arrays it's not that difficult to figure out the formula, given the HERE documentation states:

*k = num_destinations * i + j*

and

*Each entry at position k corresponds to an entry in the matix at row i and column j by the forumula: k = M * i + j*

As a result my response mapping to internal objects now looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rideRouteInfoRequests.Count; i++)
{
    var distanceIndex = matrixResponse.Matrix.NumDestinations * i + i;
    rideRouteInfoRequests[i].Distance = matrixResponse.Matrix.Distances[distanceIndex];
    var durationIndex = matrixResponse.Matrix.NumDestinations * i + i;
    rideRouteInfoRequests[i].Duration = matrixResponse.Matrix.TravelTimes[durationIndex];
}
```

This solution only works for my specific case where I input a square matrix where I expect each origin to match the corresponding (index) destination.